# Calling a stored procedure and checking the return value

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure called `pat_selectPatientById` and that stored procedure returns a true or false using `ISNULL(@isEqual, 0) as IsProviderSameAsPCP`.

I am trying to call this stored procedure using a C# method by calling `Application.WebService.ExecuteQuery("pat_selectPatientById")`. But I'm not having any luck - can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot guys

Code:

```
declare @isEqual bit = 
    (select 
        top 1 1 as IsEqual 
    from 
         Patient p 
    inner join 
         [Resource] r on p.ProviderId = r.ResourceId
    where 
        PatientId = @PatientId
        and p.PrimaryCareProviderId = r.RefPhysId)
```

Comment: Is there method for ExecuteScalar in the framework you are using?

Comment: You able to use custom code or must it go through this method you mentioned, i.e. Application.WebService.. ??

Comment: yes i am returning a value. I added a watch to the method that i was trying trying to make and was able to see the value. the watch that i add was "ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsProviderSameAsPCP"]" which returned a true or a false.

Comment: has to go through the Application.WebService

Comment: So the ExecuteQuery will return a dataset. You need to then get the table at index 0 and the row at index 0 and then Convert.ToBoolean() the value from the column IsProviderSameAsPCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the value from your stored procedure.

```
SELECT @isEqual
```

Aside that you need a `SqlConnection` object and a `SqlCommand` object to invoke the stored procedure.

```
conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("IsProviderSameAsPCP", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You can then use the `rdr` object to loop through the result set.

You can find your connection string at:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

I.e. for `SQL Server 2008`:

```
string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the value in a select. Next line in your proc needs to be

```
select @isEqual
```

ie..
    declare @isEqual bit = 
    (select 
        top 1 1 as IsEqual 
    from 
         Patient p inner join [Resource] r
         on p.ProviderId = r.ResourceId
    where 
          PatientId = @PatientId
          and p.PrimaryCareProviderId = r.RefPhysId)
    select @isEqual

ExecuteScalar is the command in C# you are looking for. You could also use an output parameter on your stored proc if you have multiple values and don't want to return a table output.